# Cannot Pick<> Type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a component like this

```
interface ElementsProps {
    a: number,
    b: string,
    c?: boolean
}

interface FooProps {
    elements: Pick<ElementsProps, "a" | "b" | "c">[]
}

const Foo = ({elements}: FooProps) => {
    const doSomething = (c: Pick<ElementsProps , "c">) => {
        return ...
    }

   return elements.map(element => doSomething(element.c))
}
```

But, this gives me

```
return elements.map(element => doSomething(element.c))
                                              ^
```

> TS2345: Argument of type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Pick<ElementsProps , "c">'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Pick<ElementsProps , "c">'.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIBsIFsLgM4AKUA9gA57IDeAsAFDIPJwBcyIArlgEbQA0djZF1Z4wUUAHN+9RggD8rLsWKY4IOgF86dUJFiIUAMWVEyFGjIYRMOfKwLAEAawA8GbLjCES5XsgBEcP7IAD4BXMFh-gj+AHwA2gC6mtq0CMQgosjGxMgAvMgAFJTWHvgarDmm5ACU+bFUArIZWQAmxADKxDhgABaS+UUI9o6u7rZe1RR+0XF1eQ0WgoJQEGDsUCDIAPTbyAB0h00MWrTHyKvrm8ilE3j7WHCkhbee9cjtXT39IBIvNp59ggajUUrQgA)

Why?

Comment: It should fail earlier than that. You're trying to call `map()` on an object type.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Sorry, my bad. Forgot the array `[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) instead of `Pick` (your type definitions make it a little awkward though):

```
interface ElementsProps {
    a: number,
    b: string,
    c?: boolean
}

interface FooProps {
    elements: Pick<ElementsProps, "a" | "b" | "c">[]
}

const Foo = ({elements}: FooProps) => {
    const doSomething = (c: FooProps['elements'][number]['c']) => {
    }

    return elements.map(element => doSomething(element.c))
}
```

Comment: It's still interesting, though, that although you can assign `undefined` to the `c` property of something with the type `ElementProps`, it won't let you pass `element.c` into `doSomething` with the OP's original definition. (But if I were typing `doSomething`, I'd type it the way you did.)

Comment: Where is the difference to `Pick` though?

Comment: `Pick` creates a new type with the selected properties. It doesn't pick a single property from a type.